# AdMob for Windows Phone 8.1 On unity3d 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8.1, admob

I am having issue with implementing banner and interstitial ads on Windows Phone 8.1. I have tried different plugins and they are are working only for Windows Phone 8. Please suggest me any plugin or a way to show ads on Windows Phone 8.1.

My unity3d version is 4.6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no official plugin. You can try [this solution](https://github.com/ScruffyFurn/Windows-Unity-Ad-Network-Plugin) or use aggregators. (etc [getadrotator](http://.com/adrotator-v2-updated-to-beta-release-of-the-v2-unity-plug-in/))